# What's the difference between tsconfig's 'outFile' and webpack config's 'output'

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

What's different between the 'output' path? Is tsconfig is a loader? And webpack to resolve '.ts' file after the run tsconfig build?
Why the file 'src.js' is not found? It is deleted by webpack automatically?

tsconfig.json:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "outFile": "src.js",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {  
    entry: './index.ts',  
    output: {  
        filename: './dest.js'  
    },  
    module: {  
        loaders: [{  
            test: /\.ts$/,  
            loader:'ts-loader'
        }]  
    },  
    resolve: {  
        extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']  
    }  
}
```

When I run 'webpack' the 'src.js' is not found and 'dest.js' is ok.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### outFile

This configuration option is used by TS compiler when using `tsc` command to

> Concatenate and emit output to single file.

You can read more about compiler options [here](https://hackernoon.com/configuring-typescript-compiler-a84ed8f87e3#f582).

#### output

This configuration option is used by `Webpack` to

> The top-level output key contains set of options instructing webpack
>   on how and where it should output your bundles, assets and anything
>   else you bundle or load with webpack.

#### Why src.js is missing

When you use `ts-loader` instead of a `tsc` as part of webpack built, the `outFile` option from `tsconfig.json` is not used. Webpack when loading a `.ts` file detects that it should be passed to `ts-loader`, which in turn uses a compiler to compile **only this one file** and then returns output to a webpack. It never works with all files the way `tsc` does. That's why no `src.js` is generated.

Comment: 1:But when I remove 'outFile' in tsconfig.json,the 'dest.js' without any my code,and they are default code by webpack to use amd generate.If I add 'outFile','dest.js' is ok.   2:When I remove tsconfig.json file,it tips error missing this file when I run 'webpack'.

Comment: @FreeTears, `_When I remove tsconfig.json file,it tips error missing this file when I run 'webpack'_ - `ts-loader` uses this file for many things other than `outFile` option, so it's required. Didn't understand your first point about `outFile`, can you elaborate?